# Accessing Private Members with Cin inside Class

Tags: c++

I'm little confused.. My Code is Below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test {
    private:
    int x, y;
  public:
    void get(){
        cin>>x;
        cin >>y;
        cout << x;
        cout << y;
    }
};

int main ()
{
  Test obj;
  obj.get();
  return 0;
}
```

In this code I'm accessing private members using cin..!! Is it fine? because I think user can send values or access private members directly after program run..!! 
I just want to ask is it safe or not..!! Thanks..!!

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "fine". It's valid C++, but inadvisable for writing safe programs.

Comment: What you really should do is get the values from the user in main and then use a 2 parameter constructor to create an object after you get the inputs.

Comment: You're accessing private members inside a member function of the class that contains them (`get` is accessing them, not `cin`), If you weren't allowed to do that, you couldn't do anything with private members.

Comment: @TartanLlama Perfect. I was just want to ask is it safe or not..!! Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have already answered, but I want to give a full answer:

```
In this code I'm accessing private members using cin..!! Is it fine?
```

In the code, you're getting values from `cin` and storing them in member variables.  That's allowed, but not a normal way to write code.  As others have stated, each `Test` object has access to its own internals, and as written, it will update those internals using data from `cin`.  It's hard to imagine a useful language that could prevent you from doing this.

```
I think user can send values or access private members directly after program run..!!
```

No, the user could not.  After the program exits, the memory is freed and all values simply cease to exist.

Even while the program is running, the user won't have access to the objects' internals.  Yes, you ask the user for values, and then immediately tell the user the values they gave you, so there are no secrets; but the user doesn't get unrestricted access to `x` and `y`.  After setting `x` to `5`, the user can't change it to `10` if the program never calls `get()` again.  You can read the source code, and mark every place that the value is allowed to change; it will never change mysteriously without you calling `get()`.  A true security hole would make it possible for the value to change without you knowing about it.

Answer (score 4):

Read more about C++ member accessors.

Private members are only accessible within the class defining them. The `get()` function belongs to the `Test` class so it can access private members.

Comment: I know about protected private etc accessing them everything..!! But was little confuse this way is fine. or not..!! thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Within a class, private controls the accessibility of the name, not the actual data. So a class member function is permitted to pass a reference to a private member to any other function.

The line

```
cin >> x;
```

is actually a call to this function

```
std::istream& std::istream::operator>>(int&)
```

The code in `get()` (a member function) can see the name the variable `x` and can therefore form a reference to it, which it then passes on to `operator>>()`. As far as the code in `operator>>()` is concerned, it could be a reference to any int anywhere.

Comment: The standards specify that the streaming operators for basic types (`int`, `bool`, etc) are member functions of a (templated) class called `basic_istream`  (`istream` is a specialisation of `basic_istream`).   Also, the extraction operator (`operator>>()`) returns a reference to an input stream, not a reference to an output stream.